Next js Api sometimes returns 404 sometimes works fine
I am using Next.js 14 and in a component of my project I need to make an api call, which works fine in the beginning but after some consecutive calls, it returns 404.
The api route is as follow:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { and, eq } from "drizzle-orm";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

import db from "@/db/drizzle";
import { getUserProgress, getUserSubscription } from "@/db/queries";
import { challengeProgress, challenges, userProgress } from "@/db/schema";

export const GET = async (req: Request) => {
const url = new URL(req.url);
const challengeId: any = url.searchParams.get("id");
if (!challengeId)
return NextResponse.json({ success: false },{ status: 401 });

try {

const { userId } = auth();
console.log("stage 1");
if (!userId) {
  throw new Error("Unauthorized");
}
console.log(userId);
const currentUserProgress = await getUserProgress();
const userSubscription = await getUserSubscription();

if (!currentUserProgress) {
  throw new Error("User progress not found");
}
console.log("stage 2");
const challenge = await db.query.challenges.findFirst({
  where: eq(challenges.id, challengeId),
});

if (!challenge) {
  throw new Error("Challenge not found");
}

const lessonId = challenge.lessonId;

const existingChallengeProgress =
  await db.query.challengeProgress.findFirst({
    where: and(
      eq(challengeProgress.userId, userId),
      eq(challengeProgress.challengeId, challengeId)
    ),
  });
console.log("stage 3");
const isPractice = !!existingChallengeProgress;

if (
  currentUserProgress.hearts === 0 &&
  !isPractice &&
  !userSubscription?.isActive
) {
  return NextResponse.json({ error: "hearts" });
}

if (isPractice) {
  await db
    .update(challengeProgress)
    .set({
      completed: true,
    })
    .where(eq(challengeProgress.id, existingChallengeProgress.id));

  await db
    .update(userProgress)
    .set({
      hearts: Math.min(currentUserProgress.hearts + 1, 5),
      points: currentUserProgress.points + 10,
    })
    .where(eq(userProgress.userId, userId));

  revalidatePath("/learn");
  revalidatePath("/lesson");
  revalidatePath("/quests");
  revalidatePath("/leaderboard");
  revalidatePath(`/lesson/${lessonId}`);
  return NextResponse.json({ success: true });
}
console.log("stage 4");
await db.insert(challengeProgress).values({
  challengeId,
  userId,
  completed: true,
});

await db
  .update(userProgress)
  .set({
    points: currentUserProgress.points + 10,
  })
  .where(eq(userProgress.userId, userId));

revalidatePath("/learn");
revalidatePath("/lesson");
revalidatePath("/quests");
revalidatePath("/leaderboard");
revalidatePath(`/lesson/${lessonId}`);

return NextResponse.json({ success: true });
} 
catch (error) {

console.log("error in api", error);
return NextResponse.json({ success: false }, { status: 401 });}

};`

while the frontend function which sends api call is
 const handleupsert = async (id: number) => {
    try {
      const r = await fetch(`/api/upsert?id=${id}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers:{
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      });

      if (!r.ok) {
        toast.error("Something went wrong agin, Please try again!");
        return;
      }
      const res = await r.json();

      console.log("got transition response");
      if (res?.error === "hearts") {
        console.log("missing hearts");
        open();
        return;
      }
      correctControls.play();
      setStatus("correct");

      setPercentage((prev) => prev + 100 / challenges.length);
      console.log("out of transition");
      //this is a practice
      if (initialPercentage === 100) {
        setHearts((prev) => Math.min(prev + 1, 5));
      }
      console.log("transition success");
      return
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error in transition", error);
      return
    }
  };

The firing of the handleupsert function is through onContinue button as follows:
 const onContinue = () => {
    console.log("onConitnue function invoked");
    if (!selectedOption) return;

    if (status === "wrong") {
      setStatus("none");
      setSelectedOption(undefined);
      return;
    }
    if (status === "correct") {
      onNext();
      console.log("run after onnext")
      setStatus("none");
      setSelectedOption(undefined);
      return;
    }
    console.log("status matched");
    const correctOption = options.find((option) => option.correct);
    if (!correctOption) return;
    console.log("got correct option");
    if (correctOption && correctOption.id === selectedOption) {  //correct option
      startTransition(async () => {
        console.log("Transition Started");
try {
  
  await handleupsert(challenge.id);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("e=",error)
}
        return;
      });
    } else {  //incorrect option
      startTransition(() => {
        reduceHearts(challenge.id)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response?.error === "hearts") {
              console.log("Missing Hearts");
              open();
              return;
            }
            inCorrectControls.play();
            setStatus("wrong");
            if (!response?.error) {
              setHearts((prev) => Math.max(prev - 1, 0));
            }
          })
          .catch(() => toast.error("Something went wrong, Please try again."));
      });
    }
  };

and onContinue function is triggered by onClick of a button.
Can somebody help me in understanding or resolving this bug?
Feel free to comment if more data is needed.
I was expecting api to execute every time the button is pressed.
